# Header and footer stucks under other containers on bigger resolutions

Tags: html, css

I have this little problem. I can`t get my site to work on different resolutions. For example on small screens it works good, but on bigger resolutions header and footer keeps stuck under other containers.

HTML:

```
  <html>


<head>
  <title>Grožio salonas „Emili”</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">

</head>

<body>


  <div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
    <div class="cover-container">


      <div class="masthead clearfix">
        <div class="inner">
          <h3 class="masthead-brand">Kontaktai</h3>

          <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
            <li>
              <a href="index.html">Pagrindinis</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="paslaugos.html">Paslaugos</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="galerija.html">Galerija</a>
            </li>

            <li class="active">
              <a href="#">Kontaktai</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="accordion">Kontaktai</button>
      <div class="panel">

        <ul style="list-style-type:none; text-align: center; margin-left: -35px;">
          <p style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">Grožio salono „Emili“ kolektyvas</p>

      </div>

      <button class="accordion">Kaip mus rasti?</button>
      <div class="panel">
          <p style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">Mus galite rasti adresu: Vytauto g. 12, Vilkaviškis</p>
        <div id="map"></div>
            <script>
              function initMap() {
                var uluru = {lat: 54.647634, lng: 23.037987};
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                  zoom: 15,
                  center: uluru
                });
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: uluru,
                  map: map
                });
              }
            </script>
            <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD2vbKp8wma2ImSg7SbFQXwRQh4DMhPQD4&callback=initMap">
            </script>
        </span>

      </div>

      <button class="accordion">Apie mus</button>
      <div class="panel">
      <center><img src="img/galerija/kolektyvas.jpg" alt="Emili kolektyvas" height="auto" width="100%"></center>

      </div>


      <script>
      var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
      var i;

      for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].onclick = function() {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (panel.style.maxHeight){
              panel.style.maxHeight = null;
          } else {
              panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + 'px';
          }
        }
      }
      </script>

 <!--

       <span class="turinys">
      <p class="pavadinimas">Kur mus rasti?</p>


      <div id="map"></div>
          <script>
            function initMap() {
              var uluru = {lat: 54.647634, lng: 23.037987};
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 15,
                center: uluru
              });
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: uluru,
                map: map
              });
            }
          </script>
          <script async defer
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD2vbKp8wma2ImSg7SbFQXwRQh4DMhPQD4&callback=initMap">
          </script>
      </span>
-->
      <div class="mastfoot">
        <div class="inner">
          <p>© 2017 Grožio salonas „Emili“ </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: logo;
    src: url(fonts/EdwardianScriptITC.ttf);
}

button.accordion {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 30px 5px 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
  border: 1px solid #680606;
  color: #ffffff;
  outline: 5;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
}


h1 {
  font-family: logo;
  font-size: 900%;
  color: #680606;
}

a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}


button{
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 0;
}

button:hover{
  border: 1px solid #680606;
  color: #680606;
  outline: 0;
}

/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
/*css for full size background image*/
  background: url(../img/backgroundsm.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);

}

#map {
      text-align: center;
        height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
       }

.pavadinimas{
  margin-top: -100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.turinys{
  text-align: left;
}

.uzsklanda{
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

#menu_apie{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;

}

#puslapiai_apie{
  width:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:left;
}

/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */
.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cover-container {
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Padding for spacing */
.inner {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}


/*
 * Header
 */
.masthead-brand {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.masthead-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.masthead-nav > li + li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.95);
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.masthead-nav > li > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #a9a9a9;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
.masthead-nav > .active > a,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:hover,
.masthead-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .masthead-nav {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
 * Cover
 */

.cover {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*
 * Footer
 */

.mastfoot {
  text-align: center;
  color: #999; /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}


/*
 * Affix and center
 */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%; /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 700px;
  }
}


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.modal-dialog {width:600px;}
.thumbnail {margin-bottom:6px;}

.galleria{ width: 100%; height: 450px; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); }
```

Here is the picture of a problem:

[The header falls under main content...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBPQ3.jpg)

Comment: made a jsfiddle but i dont see the problem https://jsfiddle.net/dfk0p3o8/

Comment: Look closer. If you scale window up, you will see how header and footer goes under those expandable tabs.

Comment: not sure how much resolution you are using, but ive maxed mine out and "Kontaktai" moves to the left and the tabs move to the right of "Kontakai"

Comment: [IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/15i2cf6.jpg[/IMG]